# Single word for `Number of times of use`?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I need to created a database column to define `Number of times of use`, is there some single word for this? If not, what's the common word for this? `numberOfTimesOfUse` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about naming, including naming programming variables/classes. See guidelines in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The number of times something is used could be summarised in the word "**uses**" (the plural of the noun 'use', as in *single-use plastic*).

For example:

> - You can use a tube of toothpaste about 50 times
> - You get about 50 uses from a tube of toothpaste